# I'm trying to search a CSV file of 1 million lines of text using 5 words in R programming and create a column for these accumulated scores

Tags: csv, search

I'm trying to search a CSV file of 1 million lines of text using 5 words in R programming and create a column for these accumulated scores.

```
`enter code here`CNN <- read.csv("CNNNewsDataSet.csv") # Properly import data


`enter code here`View(CNN)


# Load the Data in the variable 
#CNN <- read.csv("CNNNewsDataSet.csv", header = T)
`enter code here`str(CNN)

# Show CNN DataSet
`enter code here`View(CNN)


# Load that Vector or text data for just the message column as a 
Corpus. 
`enter code here`corpus <- iconv(CNN$message)
# Show CNN DataSet
`enter code here`View(corpus)

# kept only those characters I wanted using a range of ASCII codes.
`enter code here`corpus <- gsub('[^\x20-\x7E]', '', corpus)
`enter code here`View(corpus)

# Fill in blank messages with NA
`enter code here`corpus[corpus==""] <- NA
`enter code here`View(corpus)

# Omit blank messages
`enter code here`corpus<-na.omit(corpus)
`enter code here`View(corpus)


#Remove All Punctuation Characters
`enter code here`corpus <- gsub("[[:punct:][:blank:]]+", " ", corpus)
`enter code here`View(corpus)

# Converted all the text into lower case.
`enter code here`corpus<- tolower(corpus)
`enter code here`View(corpus)

# Removed numbers from the text data.
`enter code here`corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
`enter code here`View(corpus)
```

## keys and values

```
`enter code here`search_for <- data.table(
`enter code here`word=c("Capitol", "Biden", "Congress", "Marines", "Senate", "White 
House"),
`enter code here`value=c(-0.5, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2, -0.4, -0.04))

`enter code here`View(value)

`enter code here`search_res <- merge(corpus[, id:=1L], search_for[, id:=1L], by="id", 
`enter code here`allow.cartesian=TRUE)[,match:=text %like% word, by=.(text, word, 
value)][match==TRUE, .(words=paste(sort(word), collapse=", "), 
`enter code here`value=sum(value)), by=text]

`enter code here`search_res <- merge(corpus[, -"id"], search_res, on="text", 
all.x=TRUE)
`enter code here`search_res
```

I get this error below:
**Error in `:=`(id, 1L) :
Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...)
are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See
help(":=").**